# Best place to keep App's Resources (like PDF, Presentation Files and other files) which will b read and displayed by App

Tags: android, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

im developing and iPad & Android Application , which is used for Presentation purpose.
App contains many PDF, Presentation files  which are read and displayed by App using WebView.

Now the problem is , **im not sure where to keep these files ..
1) in Documents directory of (iPAd App)
2) SD card of iPAD
3) totally blank about Android ..donno where to keep them in android.**

Please help me as **these files will be Synchronized later by the app .
Synchronization** will be made to download new files from iTunes .

Thanks in advance.
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For in iOS app - the recommended place to put this information is in the Documents Directory.

Comment: Can i Do synchronization of Files from Document Directory?

Answer (score 0):

For Android: You can store this in /assets folder in your application package.
Please see this link to know how to use Assets:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html
>
> http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/using_android_assets

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you save the data in Documents directory you must ensure they are stored with the "do not backup" attribute, otherwise you will back up all the data to iCloud (and be rejected from the app store). Alternatively you can use tmp or cache folders, which can be found by login from this page: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/

2) I think you could use the SD-card as well...

3) In android you can save the data in the res/raw folder at compile time or in phone storage/sd-card during runtime. So basically if you fetch the files from somewhere I would recommend saving the data on SD-card if it is present otherwise on phone memory.

Comment: So when Any one download the app, a Document folder will be created in that Device also?

Comment: For the iOS app every app has a private Documents folder (automatically created by iOS).